# the cc file of adhoc transport protocol

Tags: network-protocols, adhoc, ns2, cc

I want to modify the ATP (adhoc transport protocol) with the help of NS2 (network simulator 2) but this very protocol is not present in the directory of ns-2.34. I tried to find out the atp.cc file but could not find it. As there is simulation of ATP using NS2 so it must have the atp.cc file. Can anyone help me by giving the link of the atp.cc file ?

Comment: Example, the ns2 `lib-atp.cc` : http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/gurtov/ns/ → → http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/gurtov/ns/lib-atp.cc

Comment: And may be TP-CRAHN ( Code is available ) http://www2.ece.gatech.edu/research/labs/bwn/papers/2009/c6.pdf → → "TP-CRAHN: A Transport Protocol for Cognitive Radio Ad-hoc Networks" ...